# approximating probability mass function from a large data

Tags: probability

I am learning elementary probability; especially I am interested in learning how to find probability mass functions and density functions from data.

I think I perfectly understand the theory: For example, let's take $X$ as a random variable which takes values $1$ to $10$ with frequencies $4,4,5,5,6,10,3,3,4,6$. I know how to calculate the relative frequency from this information, i.e. here $n=50$ data size. Now the approximate will be to perform this experiment sufficient amount of time, and then the relative frequencies converge to probabilities, and we have the distribution approximately.

Now, let's say I have data for, let's say, the last five years, 2021 to 2016, where each day I have seen a number between $0$ to $50$. Trials are independent. Based on this data, can I calculate $P[X=49]$ in $2022$ on a specific day? Thank you very much for helping me find out the PMF of such data.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4473378/approximating-probability-mass-function-from-a-large-data/4473413#4473413 already asked here

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. The phrasing of the question is a bit ambiguous: if trials are independent, then the true distribution is identical at any time, today in 2022 or in 2016.
The only thing that changes is how accurately the distribution is estimated, thanks to the larger sample in recent times. It's rare to present a problem with independent trials in the context of a time period: are you really interested in independent trials, or time series forecasting?

Comment: I am interested in the independent trial.

Comment: Then the prob mass function is as you said: for every value, the prob is the relative frequency. I have a feeling that this is not what you want to know, but I'm not sure what you're looking for?